# PHP-scripts under Apache and FPM: env[PATH] vs. $_SERVER['PATH']

Tags: php-fpm

I've configured a separate FPM-pool for an application and, among other settings, set the following:

```
env[PATH] = "/opt/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
```

A call to `phpinfo()` reports the above string as `PATH` in the "Environment"-section -- so far so good.

However, the value for `$_SERVER['PATH']` -- reported under the "PHP Variables"-section -- is `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`. I guess, that's the path Apache is started with. The trouble is, when the PHP-application calls `getenv('PATH')` it gets the latter string, which is incorrect.

Now, Apache's PATH should, probably, remain what it is -- the web-server is fronting different applications and I'd rather not modify its configuration more than is absolutely necessary. The FPM-pool's settings should overwrite those of the web-server -- is there a way to enforce that? Thanks!

(My PHP currently is 7.0.14.)

Comment: I believe `getenv()` uses either `$_ENV` or `$_SERVER`. Why are you not specifying `$_ENV` since you know you want that one?

Comment: > Why are you not specifying $_ENV 
Because I am not the application's author/maintainer...